# Linear Transformation from V to W (bijective) Show that T(v) is a basis of W if B is a basis of V.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-verification, linear-transformations

$V, W$ two vector spaces and $T: V \to W$ is a bijective linear transformation. 
$B$ is a basis of $V$. Prove that $\{T(\mathbf{v}) | \mathbf{v} \in B\}$ is a basis of $W$.

I started by doing $\mathbf{w} \in W$. And since it is bijective, therefore it's surjective so there exists a $\mathbf{v} \in V$ with $T(\mathbf{v}) = \mathbf{w}$. As $B$ is a basis of $V$ , there is $\{\mathbf{v}_1,\ \cdots,\ \mathbf{v}_t\} \subseteq B$ and $\lambda_1,\ \cdots, \ \lambda_t \in K$ with 
$$\mathbf{v} = \lambda_1\mathbf{v}_1+\cdots+ \lambda_t\mathbf{v}_t$$

So $$\mathbf{w} = T(\lambda_1\mathbf{v}_1+\cdots+ \lambda_t\mathbf{v}_t)$$ 
So $\mathbf{w}$ is a linear combination of the vectors in
$$\{T(v) | v \in B\}.$$

Then to show that $T(v),\ \mathbf{v}\in B$ is free, then I need to show that $\mathbf{w} = \mathbf{0}$ right? Which is what I was doing, but in the mark scheme they say that there exists $\{\mathbf{w}_1,\cdots,\mathbf{w}_s\}$ and constants $a_1,\ \cdots,\ a_s$ such that 
$$\mathbf{w} = a_1\mathbf{w}_1 + ..+a_s\mathbf{w}_s = 0$$ 
which I am fine with, but I don't get why the dimension of $\mathbf{w}$ goes up to $s$ as opposed to $t$. Can someone explain that part to me?

Because since its bijective, then its surjective and injective so I thought the dimension of $\mathbf{w}$ would also be the $t$ i gave for the dimension of $\mathbf{v}$? And then let ${\mathbf{y}_1,\ \cdots,\ \mathbf{y}_s}\subseteq B$ so $T(\mathbf{y}) = \mathbf{w}$. Then 
$$T(a_1\mathbf{y}_1+..+a_s\mathbf{y}_s) = \mathbf{w} = \mathbf{0}$$ 
Since it's bijective, then $a_1\mathbf{y}_1+\cdots+a_s\mathbf{y}_s = 0$ so $a_1 = a_s = 0$ so it's a basis.

Another question is, why is $\mathbf{y}$ necessary? Why can't I use $T(\mathbf{v}) = \mathbf{w}$ and then make 
$$T(\lambda_1\mathbf{v}_1+\cdots+\lambda_s\mathbf{v}_s) = \mathbf{w} = \mathbf{0}$$ 
and show $\lambda_1 = \lambda_s = 0$? I realize it's because we have given $\mathbf{w}$ a dimension of $s$ instead of $t$, so $\mathbf{v}$ can't go up to $s$. Which comes back to my main confusion, why are there 2 different dimensions, $s$ and $t$?

Comment: The image spans $W$, so it is surjective and $T$ of a basis is a spanning set by linearity. However $T$ is injective, so that the image of a basis must be linearly independent.

Comment: I've cleaned up your notation a bit. One point I wish to confirm: In the question, you ask things like "but I don't get why the dimension of w goes up to s as opposed to t." You used the lowercase "w" which I assume meant the vector $\mathbf{w}$ instead of the vector space $W$. Of course, this makes no sense as individual vectors have no dimension. I just want to ask whether this is a typo or a misunderstanding of concepts which an answer might (and should) address?

Comment: @EuYu thanks for cleaning up the notation :P yes i meant the vector w where w = {w1.....ws}

Comment: @EuYu i just dont get why it goes up to s, not t. Like rogerl who answered the question below did the same as i was suggesting in my question, using a1T(v1)...atT(vt) instead of introducing a new vector y in B that goes up to s.

Answer (score 1):

To show that $\{T(v_i) | v_i \in B\}$ is a basis for $W$, you have to show that it spans and that it is linearly independent. You showed that it spans. To see that it is linearly independent, suppose that
$$a_1T(v_1) + \cdots + a_tT(v_t) = 0.$$
Since $T$ is linear, we have $T(a_1v_1+ \cdots + a_tv_t) = 0$; since $T$ is injective, it follows that $a_1v_1 + \cdots + a_tv_t = 0$. But the $v_i$ are linearly independent, so all the $a_i$ are zero and thus the $T(v_t)$ are linearly independent as well.

Comment: exactly that's what i put however in the mark scheme they put that i have to introduce a new vector y such that a1y1+ ..asys = 0. That is a different dimension to t. my main question is why have they used w going up to s instead of t? That is why they use y instead of v. because y has dimension s whereas v has dimension t. ?